# Generating protobuf c++ code inside Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, cmake, android-ndk, protocol-buffers

I am trying to build a bridge between Java and C++ using Protobuf for serialization and storage purpose, inside an Android Studio project. Things work well on the Java side. Using the JavaLite plugin, I am able to generate the classes for each file.

Where things start to break is trying to do the same on the native side. I've tried many things and I came to the conclusion that using `cmake` would be the best way to get there. However, I am running into some issues.

1. `Cmake` doesn't seem to know about `protobuf`. When I add these lines to `CMakeList.txt`:

`include(FindProtobuf)
 find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
 include_directories(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})`

I am getting:

> -- Could NOT find Protobuf (missing:  Protobuf_LIBRARIES Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR)

which is strange since my version passes the smoke test:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
```

Sanity check, from terminal:

```
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.5.1
```

What are the other option to generate C++ protobuf in Android Studio? Would NDK-build be another option?

Comment: Don't do that: `include(FindProtobuf)`. Any CMake script with a name stared with "Find" is intended only for `find_package()` calls.

Comment: Also, using protobuf in *development* implies existence not only `protoc` *executable*, but also some *libraries* and *header* files. `find_package(Protobuf)` search for a header file `google/protobuf/service.h` and `protobuf` library file. Make sure that you have given files installed in your system.

Comment: Cold you resolve this issue? 
I am experiencing the same problem, did you have a chance to resolve it?
I am trying to run it inside docker.
The protobuf I am using is "libprotoc 3.18.0" and observing the same error.